# What is vikarma specifically?

Tags: karma

While looking up ***vikarma***, I'm not finding any specifics. Most translations I read say "sinful" or "forbidden" activities, but that's not very specific. It doesn't really say what these "sinful" or "forbidden" activities are. One even says "work without sense"; what does that mean?

Can someone clear this up for me, and explain in detail what is ***vikarma*** and what kind of actions build it?

Answer (score 3):

**Let me tell you first WHY Hindu texts are not THAT "specific" like the Holy Books of Abhrahamic religions.** Why they usually just tell about the the different spiritual states, and leave up to the seeker, to trace **HIS OWN** path from one state to other (and eventually to the Absolute). Actually this is common in every aspect of Hinduism. And **the reason is because there are ALWAYS innumerable paths between any two states,** to be specific. Similarly, there are innumerable paths leading to self-realization, of the *God in self*.

Anyway now lets jump to answering your question.

The phrase "work without sense", means **you should not "react" to the temptations and desires, forced upon you by your sense organs.** Senses can ONLY react, on their objects of attachments i.e either in present, or in memory of past, or in imagination of future. That reaction, passing through your "Logical and Intelligent" Brain, and tends to gain complete control of your conscious mind, making you driven by chaos, a creator of "spiritual entropy".

Desires are like a grand ships, in the ocean of mind, ready to sail on the voyage of self gratification, burning the fuel of "your" will. BUT the point here is that those ships itself are, actually made of ICE. **Their destiny is to melt back into mind eventually**. But till then you would be occupied wasting time in increasing the "Spiritual Entropy" of your system. So its better not to let your mind "freeze", so that the "ships" of desires can melt, as early as possible.

**Whatever** that tends to completely occupy your consciousness and making you to forget your divine self is a "Sinful" activity. All spiritual-chaos generating, states of mind i.e *Kaama, Krodha, Lobha, Moha, Madd, and Matsarya*, have the same tendency to occupy the mind. ONLY these "enemies" have the power to generate ARMY of desires attacking your mind.

- SO any ***Karma* done to quench any such desires INSIDE our own self is Vikarma**.
- Any ***Karma* done to quench SIMILAR desires in other being i.e OUTSIDE our own self is ("Good") Karam**.
- And doing **Karma, by keeping *Dharma* as guide is Akarma.** You are not here to quench your thirst OR even the thirst of others, **but to REALIZE that the "thirst" itself is a delusion.**

**At last** please NOTE that that worrying too much about Sin, Virtue, Heaven or Hell, "good", "bad", is a trait of Abrahamic religions. Hindu stress more on his own *Dharma*, rather than on Karma or Vikarma. Because free will ("to apply outside"), is the BIGGEST delusion of this *Dukkhalaya Ashashvatt Sansaar*. A Hindu knows that if he is always with his higher self and Dharma, everything will fall into place **automatically** on its own.

**NOTE:** I seldom provide references when I present my views on the subject, because I think looking up to a book every time you "think!", is a again NOT a hindu trait. Vedas were in souls of ancient sages, they did not mug it up either. **Reading Vedas should be a journey of Mind to soul, rather than of memory from one synapse to the other.**

Mind you, that there is a difference between Vedas and books of other religion. **"Vedas" are NOT "Holy" as in "Holy Bible" or "Holy Quran", but they can for sure MAKE YOU HOLY.**

Comment: Any suggestions for online reading material in english on: All spiritual-chaos generating, states of mind i.e Kaama, Krodha, Lobha, Moha, Madd, and Matsarya? I'm not finding much on google.

Comment: Yeah people these days have these things inside their-selves

Comment: @Hindu, can you cite your sources. Your explanation of Karma, Akarma & Vikarma are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Karma - doing Dharmic action and wanting its fruits
e.g. doing job with expectation of salary and desiring to spend it on nice food, clothes, cars, movies etc.
There is nothing wrong with Karma. However it won't lead you to Moksha.

Akarma - doing Dharmic action without wanting its fruits
e.g. doing job without expectation of salary, just because it is your duty. But salary will come anyways, although you have no intention of enjoying it for yourself, rather spending it to help family, charity etc.
There is nothing wrong with Akarma, AND it will lead you to Moksha.

Vikarma - doing ADharmic actions
e.g. drinking, gambling, lying etc.
There is no question of expecting or not expecting fruits, because ADharmic actions should not be done at all. There are rare exceptions where you do such actions for the sake of  establishing Dharma (e.g. Krishna lied to protect Dharma).